# Why PhpStorm inspection says `Exception` is undefined?

Tags: php, ide, editor, phpstorm

`PhpStorm` doesn't recognize `Exception` from some reason. The code executes fine, but I cannot "go to" code (which should send me to `Core_c.php`):

[image]

Comment: Try \Exception to use the root namespace.

Comment: If you are using namespaces, then see the comment above, otherwise please try **File | Invalidate Caches**

Comment: @phpisuber01: I use `\Exception`, otherwise it wouldn't have executed. And it does execute..

Comment: @LazyOne: cheers! thanks! post an answer so I can accept it.

Comment: I tried @LazyOne's suggestion to use \Exception which worked since I'm using namespaces. I also tried adding "Use Exception;" to the beginning of the code and dropped the \ and it worked as well.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Windows OS has "try rebooting the OS" advice which helps in a lot of "does not work / suddenly stopped working" scenarios.

**File | Invalidate Caches** is the one for PhpStorm, especially after IDE/OS crash or after upgrading your IDE to a newer version.

P.S.
I had to make up some text, otherwise it's too short for an answer.