# PhpStorm not recognising core PHP

Tags: php, phpstorm

PhpStorm isn't recognising core PHP. For example, it's not recognising `Exception`, with the tooltip saying "Undefined class 'Exception'".

I've tried invalidating the cache to no avail. I've checked a colleague's installation and they appear to have no issues, and after `Ctrl+Clicking` on their `Exception` class, it links correctly to `Core_c.php`, which isn't the case for me. It seems like my PhpStorm isn't picking up the PHP plugin / library, and I have no idea why.

I've tried reinstalling PhpStorm to the latest version, upgrading all of my packages. I've even made sure that the php.jar plugin is actually there, and it is:

```
/opt/phpstorm/plugins/php/lib/php.jar
```

And the PHP plugin is enabled in PhpStorm.

Another problem I have with PhpStorm is that it isn't suggesting function names whenever I type them. Help would be appreciated, and I can provide additional information if needed.

Comment: Are you using namespaces? Write "\" in front of Exception (ex. `catch(\Exception $e)`)

Comment: Yes, and the code we are using is on a shared private subversion repository which everyone in my team uses, and has no issue with regarding this issue.

Comment: And in _project_ tool window, you can't see External Libraries->PHP Runtime?

Comment: Nope. This is all I have - http://imgur.com/a/ei9TJ. The External Libraries section doesn't expand, and double clicking it reveals that window.

Comment: 1) Please check your `idea.log` (Help | Show Log in XXX) for possible hints; please share it; 2) Does `Ctrl+Click` and code completion works in other file types (like JavaScript, HTML, CSS)? 3) Does it work in brand new project? 4) Does it make any difference if you disable ALL 3rd party (not bundled by default) plugins?

Comment: The question belongs on the PhpStorm helpdesk.

Comment: @LazyOne I have a lot of log files. Do you want me to supply you with all of them? `CTRL+Click` completion does work in other file types. I get the same issue in new projects.

Comment: Just last one, actual `idea.log` is enough -- make sure it's the most fresh (you may close IDE; delete all logs/files there; start IDE -- wait till it loads and try that Ctrl+Click & code completion; after that close IDE and share that log file.) Can you please also show how your .php file looks like (the one that does not work). Ideally whole IDE window -- using  Default unmodified color schema. **P.S.** If anything -- you may backup and delete IDE-wide settings and start from scratch (last resort option)

Comment: http://pastebin.com/ddSWVXjk - latest log file. Also, I get these errors in any PHP file that extends php core functionality, etc. This is a screenshot of a file from a freshly installed laravel project: http://imgur.com/a/qFbda

Comment: 1) Please temporarily disable ALL custom plugins (vue.js in particular) 2) Please provide screenshot of `Settings | Languages & Frameworks | PHP` -- I want to see "Advanced settings" part (what path you have there) -- it's on the bottom of that screen collapsed by default

Comment: http://imgur.com/oA1o9Of - There is no path. I disabled all custom plugins, including Vue.js, and I still have the issue.

Comment: OK ... two possible solutions that I can suggest here: **1)** download php stubs from https://github.com/JetBrains/phpstorm-stubs repo and use that field to point to a local version .. or just add it as "Include path" **2)** start from scratch (close IDE; backup and delete IDE-wide settings; launch IDE and do not import settings from older version). Such settings would [typically be](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/206544519-Directories-used-by-the-IDE-to-store-settings-caches-plugins-and-logs) in `~/.Phpstorm2016.3`

Comment: 3) Otherwise -- use "Submit a request" link (top of the page) at https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us to contact JetBrains support team directly

Comment: PhpStorm fails to read stubs (exception is clearly shown in the log) .. but I know no other place where such path can be stored (except maybe "File | Default Settings" but then it should propagate to new project) ... and log file does not show what path IDE is trying to use (so no suggestions at where to look in config files for that). It may also be file permission issues.. but no hints from me on this. Therefore contacting official support is the best choice here.

Comment: Thanks, I will do just that. I downloaded stubs and included them as a path in my projects, and that seems to have resolved my issue. Perhaps it's an issue with this current version - I will possibly downgrade to the previous version. Thanks again.

Comment: @BeautifulChaos There are no such issues with current versions -- it's an issue on **your local** PC/installation. So far I have not seen any similar reports (that are publicly visible -- here at SO, PhpStorm Forum, PhpStorm Issue Tracker). If they are they either Support tickets or other private reports. In long term it will be better for you to have it properly resolved

Comment: @LazyOne yes, I have found that out for myself. I backed up my configuration file and removed it as you suggested. PhpStorm appears to be functioning optimally now. I'm still at odds as to why it was an issue, as my file permissions are fine and I haven't modified them in any way other than directly through PphStorm's settings.

Comment: Yeah, this's a known problem which is quite rare, though. I'll extend log files so we have more chances to catch it. Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: @LazyOne Thank you for troubleshooting, it helps a lot!

Comment: @BeautifulChaos I suggest you to answer your own question -- it will be useful for others in similar situation + it will be more visible (easier to find) as it has an answer.

Comment: It looks like you installation may be incomplete. Did you try reinstalling and creating a new fresh project to see if it is there?

Comment: This worked for me: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13417624/why-phpstorm-inspection-says-exception-is-undefined

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe we should consider some things here. What version of PHP are you using. Not all version of PHP supports Exception and the namespaces does matter except you are using a dependency manager which may come configured with its namespace but if you are building from scratch, you may want to consider the namespace and the version PHP

Answer (score 14):

In case that same issue appears for PhpStorm 2020.1 or later,
that's a previously reported issue and invalidating caches won't help anymore.

As described [here](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-54626) the solution is:

1. Close IDE
2. Locate folder where PhpStorm 2020.2 stores indexes/caches on your computer (see below)
3. Delete that folder (as standard "Invalidate caches" does not help here)
4. Launch IDE

Typical locations for caches folder for different OS:

- Windows: `%USERPROFILE%\AppData\Local\JetBrains\PhpStorm2020.2\caches`
- Linux: `~/.cache/JetBrains/PhpStorm2020.2/caches`
- macOS: `~/Library/Caches/JetBrains/PhpStorm2020.2/caches`

https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WI-54626

Comment: This should be marked as solution, in my humble opinion.

Comment: Solved from this!

Answer (score 4):

If you are working with php below 7.1, Exception won't work because it does not implement the Throwable class. The only way for your exception to work is if you extend the Exception class.What I also do is to put a slash before the exception. Like `throw new \InvalidArgumentException`. Hopefully this works for you. Good luck